# How to manually create a android project using a template (without using eclipse)?

Tags: java, android, xml, templates, command-line

I am trying to create a new android project using the BlankActivity Template.  However, this page here: http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/templates.html only has instructions on how to do it in Eclipse.  How can I use templates manually(from the command line) without using Eclipse?  I've looked online and there doesn't seem to be much information about it.  Using "Android -h create project", I saw that there is a "-g" flag used for "gradle-templates" but I don't think that's the same as what I'm looking for and even if it was I'm not sure how to correctly use that flag.  Is using templates just not a feature the command line tools have?  Any help would be nice, thanks.

Comment: I can't offer much thats helpful when I dabbled in android stuff last year I found http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-cmdline.html this link usefull.

Comment: Yea, thanks, but I already read that.  It was useful when I was figuring out how to add libraries manually but it doesn't seem to say anything about templates.

Comment: Hey, have you found a way to do that? I'm also look for a solution. Thanks.